# Android:How to send data from server to android with no request from the android?

Tags: android, networking, upload, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How can I send data from a server to an Android device without the device polling for data?

Answer (score 4):

This is called a server side 'push' and is commonly referred to as 'pushing'. This is a well known feature of the iPhone, however, it does not currently exist on the Android. Android Cloud 2 Device messaging has not yet been released to the general development community. you may want to check out projects such as [MQTT](http://mqtt.org/) and [Deacon](http://deacon.daverea.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You might consider using Googles [cloud to device messaging](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html) for a solution.
You'll have to [sign up](http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/signup.html) for an account and are only able to use AppEngine servers at the moment.

Your application has to use API level 8 (2.2) in order to be able to receive the cloud's pushes.

Answer (score 1):

GCM (Google Cloud Messaging) is the easiest way, and while GCM provides the basic service of sending messages, there are companies out there that do help you get up and running.

You could take a look at companies like urban airship, xtify and mBlox (developer.mblox.com) to get started with this and have a few additional tools that help you structure the push notifications in a more structured way.

Good Luck with your development!